# Statements - Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E/F$ be  Galois extension.

I want to show the following:

- $F\leq K_1\leq K_2\leq E\Rightarrow \mathcal{G}(E/K_1)\geq \mathcal{G}(E/K_2)$
- $H_1\leq H_2\leq \mathcal{G}(E/F)\Rightarrow \mathcal{F}(H_1)\geq \mathcal{F}(H_2)$

Could you give me some hints how we could show these relations?

Comment: have you tried using the definitions?

Comment: We have the following definitions: $$\mathcal{F}(H)=\{x\in E : \sigma (x)=x, \forall \sigma \in H\} \\ \mathcal{G}(K)=\text{Gal}(E/K)=\{\sigma \in G: \sigma (x)=x, \forall x\in K\}$$ @Ferra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for the first one (and then deduce for the other one, use Galois corresponde or whatever, etc.):

$$\sigma\in\text{Gal}(E/K_2)\implies \sigma(k_2)=k_2\;,\;\forall\;k_2\in K_2$$

but $\;K_1\le K_2\implies\;$ the above is true in $\;K_1\;$ ...

Comment: Let $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/K_2)$ then $\sigma (k_2)=k_2, \forall k_2\in K_2$. Since $K_1\leq K_2$ we have that this is true for all $k_1\in K_1$, so $\sigma (k_1)=k_1, \forall k_1\in K_1$, therefore, $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E/K_1)$. Is this correct? 
$$$$ 
Let $h_2 \in H_2$, then $h_2 (x)=x$ in $\mathcal{F}(H_2)$. Since $H_1\leq H_2$ we have that this is true for all $h_1\in H_1$, so $h_1(x)=x$ in $\mathcal{F}(H_1)$. Therefore, $\mathcal{F}(H_2)\leq \mathcal{F}(H_1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: The first one is correct, the second confuses me: I'd say that for (2) you *must begin* with $\;f\in\mathcal F(H_2)\;$ and then prove that $\;f\in\mathcal F(H_1)\;$ , too.

Comment: Ah ok... Let $f\in \mathcal{F}(H_2)$ then $\sigma (f)=f, \forall \sigma \in H_2$. For all $\sigma\in H_1$, this relation is true, and so $f\in \mathcal{F}(H_1)$. Is this correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Basically, yes: it is correct. I'd though rather write instead of  "for all..." : "since $\;H_1\le H_2\;$ , we get that $\;\gamma f= f\;\;\;\forall\,\gamma\in H_1\;$ **too**, and thus $\;f\in\mathcal F(H_1)\;$ as well".

Comment: Ah ok... Thank you very much!! :-)